# Repopulate an accidentally deleted heroku db from console output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I made a mistake and accidentally delete all records from Attachment model in production.

I could at least get all the records from the console output (I previously did a simple Attachment.all and get all records hash displayed on screen).

This is a sample of actual output:

```
=> [#<Attachment id: 50, shortcut: "1eo2", attachment_file_name: "tumblr_lbxifqK2LT1qa0qyy.jpg", attachment_content_type: "image/jpeg", attachment_file_size: 80960, attachment_updated_at: "2010-12-22 07:39:01", created_at: "2010-12-22 07:39:02", updated_at: "2011-03-07 02:14:05", post_id: nil, about_me: nil, is_nsfw: nil, attachable_id: nil, attachable_type: nil, is_default: nil, temp_token: nil, user_id: 1, description: nil, visits: nil>, 
#<Attachment id: 51, shortcut: "1fp7", attachment_file_name: "tumblr_lbxig3Qzrg1qa0qyy.jpg", attachment_content_type: "image/jpeg", attachment_file_size: 75532, attachment_updated_at: "2010-12-22 08:04:00", created_at: "2010-12-22 08:04:01", updated_at: "2011-03-07 02:14:05", post_id: nil, about_me: nil, is_nsfw: nil, attachable_id: nil, attachable_type: nil, is_default: nil, temp_token: nil, user_id: 1, description: nil, visits: nil>, 
#<Attachment id: 52, shortcut: "1ghq", attachment_file_name: "tumblr_lbh5dvOZMf1qa4bk9o1_500.jpg", attachment_content_type: "image/jpeg", attachment_file_size: 68396, attachment_updated_at: "2010-12-22 08:04:32", created_at: "2010-12-22 08:04:33", updated_at: "2011-03-07 02:14:05", post_id: nil, about_me: nil, is_nsfw: nil, attachable_id: nil, attachable_type: nil, is_default: nil, temp_token: nil, user_id: 1, description: nil, visits: nil>,
```

Question is how can I parse this log an put them again the database and there a way to also keep the original ID and avoid having a new one? (I got other relationships by ID with other models).

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way that you might be able to do it would be something similar to this:

1) Load all the console input into a string. Take off the brackets at the beginning/end (the square ones). Then, use this Regex to get the contents of each Attachment object:

```
#<Attachment (.*)>,
```

So, something like

```
consolestr.scan(/#<(Attachment .*)>,/).each do |attachment|
```

which should give you an array consisting of each Attachment object.

2) Split the properties of each Attachment object on comma to get the full property, then on colon to get the key value pair. Something like:

```
properties = {}
attachment.split(",").each do |property|
    s = property.split(":")
    key = s[0]
    value = s[1]
    properties[key] = value
end
```

3) Re-create the record:

```
Attachment.create(properties)
```

Unfortunately I'm not at a place where I can fully test this right now, but I think it should work in theory. You may have to do some additional tinkering with the `value` that you capture, such as removing the quotes on string values, as well. Hopefully this is at least one way that can get you started recovering that data. I'm sure you are very nerve racked right now!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the database back to exactly where it was before you nuked it, your best option is to take the console output and transform it into raw SQL INSERT statements.

Creating the objects through a Rails console will re-assign the ID field, which will then break any existing object associations you've got.